# Is the book "Bioinformatics for Geneticists" outdated?

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics, book-recommendation, biotechnology

I am going to be working with genetics data in my organization's data warehouse next year and helping our biotechnology department.  I work in academic research, but I have very little genomics background.  I was able to find the book called "Bioinformatics for Geneticists" (Edited by Michael R. Barnes & Ian C. Gray) at a used book store for a couple dollars.  It looks like it was published in 2003.  Do you think this book is too outdated, or would I still get a good introduction to the subject?  If you think it's too outdated, what book(s) do you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't read through all of it, but from the second edition, which I found available online [here](http://ibi.cqupt.edu.cn/download/bioinformatics/Bioinformatics+for+Geneticists+2ed.pdf), it seems to me that it might be a good introduction, but (as expected from the publishing date) it is really missing out on all the next generation sequencing stuff. Which is important, not only because it is my favourite field.

I am not sure what you want to get from it? You say you have little genomics background, but then you got a book that expects you to know the genetics, but explains the bioinformatics.
There's a basic description of the background of sequencing at the [NIH website](http://www.genome.gov/25019999), maybe that helps.

Comment: The hyperlink of "here" is not working for me.  Which country are you in?

Comment: Germany. It is loading slowly,though. But it works, and I checked, it is not as site we might have some kind of paid subscription for.

Comment: After it downloaded, I got an exe.  What happens when you run it?  I didn't want to open it at work, so I will wait until I get home and test it.

Comment: Well, for me it's just a pdf. Maybe you got an exe for a pdf-reader? I was looking at it from a Mac, so no exe at all.

Comment: Yah, maybe.  I'll try it tonight.  Yep, this was Windows.  I'm in the US by the way, but that shouldn't matter.  I was asking because of the latency.  It took several minutes to download.

Comment: Well, it is a whole book, with graphs and all. I guess you just need to be more patient or find a faster internet connection. ;-)